# fixed width responsive design on mobile phone

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a little problem with design. You can visit [here](http://kirimundangan.com) and check from inspect element then click the 'Toggle device mode'. Set to 320 x 568 and then try to swap left.

You can see the white space on the right side :

[image]

How can I make it fixed width?

Comment: in which browser you are facing the problem..i have checked in crome and firefox and its fine..

Comment: @GauravAggarwal check in ff and see in mobile version. Its because of row class as it takes negative margin.

Comment: still the same.. @Leothelion

Comment: @Maii m checking the site and i can't see any gap.. where and in which resolution you are looking?

Comment: 320 x 568 @Leothelion

Comment: @Maii decrease the size of Keunggulan and you are done.

Comment: thank you so much.. @Leothelion

Comment: My pleasure that i helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see "row" class which is the reason of gap as it takes extra maring. Do one thing add this in your css

`.row{margin:0px !important;}`

Also there is a `h2 section` (Keunggulan) which is taking 3em size and by this under 320, it take white space so better solution is reduce the size of it in media query and and you are done.

For media query refference

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
   section h2{font-size: 2.5em;} /*adjust according to your need*/
}
```